# Transaction Manager not getting ROLLBACKed

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions

In my application we are using TX Manager.
My application is built on JSF and RF3.3 with JDBC connectivity to MYSQL
Here's the scenario:-

1. User enter value on GUI.
2. after collecting all data in Backing Bean I get the instance of Transaction Manager.
3. Then i begin the TX.
4. All the values are inserted in DB1.
5. SOAP call is made to insert values in another DB2.
6. In case insertion in DB2 fails entry from DB1 should roll back.
   7.For this I use tx.rollBack().

Problem  is although tx.rollBack is executed even then the entry is not removed.
I tried declaring afterRollBackAction and fired a delete query in DB1 but it gives me an exception

> `org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Transaction TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: a7c198d:6:4eccc549:a status: ActionStatus.ABORTED > cannot proceed STATUS_ROLLEDBACK; - nested throwable: (javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: a7c198d:6:4eccc549:a status: ActionStatus.ABORTED > cannot proceed STATUS_ROLLEDBACK)`

I checked my code properly..There is not exception (NPE or SQL or Any other kind of exeption thrown)..

Can you please tell me why the TX is not rolling back and deleting entry from the DB1?

Code Snippet :-

```
try
{
txManager.begin()

cStmt.setString(1,Name);
cStmt.setString(2,Address);
cStmt.setString(3,Number);
cStmt.registerOutParameter(10, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
cStmt.execute();
int errorCode=cStmt.getShort(10);
if(errorCode==0)
{
WebService Stub =new WebServiceStub();
CreateIdentity create=new CreateIdentity();
create.setName(Name);
create.setAddress(Address);
create.setNumber(Number);
CreateIdentityResponse createResponse=stub.createIdentity(create);
int errorCodeFromWebService=createResponse.getMsg();
 switch(errorCodeFromWebService)
{
case 0:
errorCode=0;
 txmanager.commit();

break;
case -1:
txManager.rollback();
break;
default:
txManager.rollback();
}
else
{
txManager.rollback();
}
return errorCode;
```

Although txManager.rollback gets called but rollback itself is not happening. I tried using actions before and after rollback but to no avail.

Comment: Some code will help... I think that error is because you are running it at the end of a transaction rollback but I'm not too sure about that.

Comment: Are your tables InnoDB? If they are MyISAM, then they are not under transaction control and can't be rolled back.

Comment: I tried it before rollback and after rollback..Both ways it gives the same exception....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mark Rotteveel pointed out if your tables use MyIsam engine transactions does not work. If you are using InnoDB engine check the autocommit property of your jdbc connection/jdbc driver, it should be set to false.

Comment: another option, since you are calling a stored procedure is that the stored procedure ends with a commit inside its sql code.

Comment: Absolutely spot on..I never realised the stored procedure thing....Thanks a lot...